# Add many button in Xib in iOS

Tags: ios, uibutton, xib

I have requirement to add many button large size but its not coming within view bound what should i implement .

Comment: hello please i am new and i have problem please help me istead vote down

Comment: Change the frame of buttons or if u have many buttons use scrollview to hold the buttons.

Comment: We'd like to, but you have not made an understandable question.

Comment: in given xib space is small, and i need to add more button about 10, i try also scroll view it didt work

Comment: paste the code in the question .. so that we can help you!

Comment: i added scroll view in xib but still i can place less button, scroll only work in simulator not in xib,

Comment: i added all these things throug xib

Comment: @user2256034 placing buttons in xib is your Problem?????

Comment: shoul i add the buttons with coding

Answer (score 2):

You can do it like this,

First in xib file add scrollview in your main view and than get another view in your screen which have large size dont add it to your main view but create different panel near it and than connect both scrollview and large contentview in .h file like this,

First in xib file

[image]

In .h file connect both contentView and scrollView,

```
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIView *contentView;
@property (strong, nonatomic) IBOutlet UIScrollView *scrollview;
```

Than in .m file add contentView to scrollView and make scrollview size to fit contentView,

```
- (void)viewDidLoad
{
    [super viewDidLoad];
    [scrollview addSubview:self.contentView];
    scrollview.contentSize = self.contentView.frame.size;

}
```

Comment: thanks for that, i have more task, need t add buttons dynamically

Answer (score 0):

You should use scrollview and then add those button in that scrollview. ScrollView is used when you have to use controls whose size is greater then your screen size.
You can increase its content size.

Hope it helps you.